# How to convert outputs into units of stress intensity (MPa sqrt[meters])

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The stress intensity at crack tips is commonly described in terms of MPa sqrt[m]. This is a difficult unit, and Mathematica prefers to return answers in sqrt[J]sqrt[MPa]/m, for which the numerical value is 1000x larger.

This can be confirmed with:

```
   Quantity[1, (Sqrt["Joules"] Sqrt["Megapascals"])/("Meters")]/ Quantity[1, "Megapascals" Sqrt["Meters"]]
```

The most obvious solution:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, (Sqrt["Joules"]*Sqrt["Megapascals"])/
  "Meters"], "MPa m^0.5"]
```

Just returns the input. I would like an output in the form:

```
Quantity[0.001, ("Megapascals"  Sqrt["Meters"] )]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
u = UnitConvert[
  Quantity[1, (Sqrt["Joules"]*Sqrt["Megapascals"])/"Meters"], 
  "Megapascals" Sqrt["Meters"]]

InputForm @ u
(* Quantity[1/1000, "Megapascals"*Sqrt["Meters"]] *)
```